# Android Jetpack Compose Data Class Recomposition from update within Sub Function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've been debugging an issue where Jetpack Compose would wipe out all of my changes to one address field whenever I edited another.  In the end, I solved it, but I do not understand why my solution works.  It suggests that I'm missing some key component in how Kotlin (or Jetpack Compose) works.

Below is a snippet of code.  The commented-out code does not work.  The code above it does.  The only difference between the two is how I define the function.  At first, I thought Kotlin was somehow caching the function declaration, which is what led me to use val assignment instead (so it would recreate the function on every call).

That fixed the problem, but then I also realized this function gets called on every key press, and my assumption could not be correct because the component was retaining state for multiple value changes in the same field.  It's only when you change fields that all your previous data gets wiped out.

I have no idea why. I suspect it has something to do with how Jetpack Compose is using equality to determine what items to recompose but I can't think how this could be, especially since it's the function itself that doesn't seem to be recomposed.

I feel as though I'm missing an important aspect of how either Jetpack Compose or Kotlin (and maybe even the underlying Java) works.  That makes me really nervous.  I would appreciate any insight into the matter.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Address(
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  config: AddressConfiguration = AddressConfiguration(),
  address: AddressResponse = AddressResponse(),
  onUpdate: (response: AddressResponse, isValid: Boolean) -> Unit,
) {

  val onChange: (update: AddressUpdate) -> Unit = { update ->
    val response = when (update) {
      is AddressUpdate.Component -> address.copyWith(update.component, update.value)
      is AddressUpdate.Address -> update.address
    }
    val isValid = config.isValid(response)
    onUpdate(response, isValid)
  }
  
//  fun onChange(update: AddressUpdate): Unit {
//    val response = when (update) {
//      is AddressUpdate.Component -> address.copyWith(update.component, update.value)
//      is AddressUpdate.Address -> update.address
//    }
//    val isValid = config.isValid(response)
//    onUpdate(response, isValid)
//  }

...
}
```

More info:
`AddressResponse` is a data class. The `copyWith` function is basically a when statement that takes an enum and copies the `AddressResponse` with the new value in the appropriate field.

The entire component is large, so I don't include all of it's code, but this is the `AddressResponse` component:

```kotlin
data class AddressResponse(
  val address1: String? = null,
  val address2: String? = null,
  val city: String? = null,
  val province: String? = null,
  val postalCode: String? = null,
  var country: String? = null,
) {
  fun componentValue(component: AddressComponent): String? = when (component) {
    Address1 -> address1
    Address2 -> address2
    City -> city
    Province -> province
    PostalCode -> postalCode
    Country -> country
  }

  fun copyWith(component: AddressComponent, value: String?): AddressResponse = when (component) {
    Address1 -> copy(address1 = value)
    Address2 -> copy(address2 = value)
    City -> copy(city = value)
    Province -> copy(province = value)
    PostalCode -> copy(postalCode = value)
    Country -> copy(country = value)
  }
}
```

Example of `onChange` definition and usage (note: InputField is a private component I can't share here, but it essentially wraps TextField and has been tested extensively):

```kotlin
private sealed class AddressUpdate {
  data class Component(val component: AddressComponent, val value: String?) : AddressUpdate()
  data class Address(val address: AddressResponse) : AddressUpdate()
}

private typealias OnChange = (update: AddressUpdate) -> Unit
```

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun TextInput(
  component: AddressComponent,
  config: AddressConfiguration,
  value: String?,
  onChange: OnChange,
) {
  val validity = config.valueValidity(component, value)
  InputField(
    Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    inputFieldState = when (validity) {
      Valid -> InputFieldState.default()
      InValid -> InputFieldState.error(errorMessage = "")
      is Error -> InputFieldState.error(errorMessage = validity.message)
    },
    value = value ?: "",
    label = config.label(component),
    onValueChanged = { onChange(AddressUpdate.Component(component, it)) },
    keyboardType = if (component === PostalCode) KeyboardType.Number else KeyboardType.Text
  )
}
```

Comment: could you provide a code with usage of `onChange` function (or variable)?

Comment: @tasjapr Definition and usage of `onChange` has been added.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's a Compose bug or oversight that it doesn't recompose locally declared functions with that syntax, so the function is capturing and using the original values from the first composition? You could try adding an ID property to your AddressResponse class and logging it from within this composable and from within your local function to see.